# How to prepare full bleed stickers to print in AI

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, print-production

I need to prepare stickers with lots of detail for printing. The trick is customer want full bleed. Is there any smarter idea how to do that in AI than drawing it by hand?

[image]

Comment: Well yeah you can make a copy behind and offset it, but it dont work so well on color boundaries. That could be fixed with a but of code though

Comment: Or just copy behind and add strokes... really depends upon the artwork. But the reality is.. for quality, by hand is best. There's no shortcut to craftsmanship.